# OAuth in Spring Security 5.2.x: Store userInfo response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We are running an API on Sping Boot 2.2 and are consequently using Sping Security 5.2. In securing this API with OAuth, we are using the new features built into Spring Security (since the Spring Security OAuth project is now deprecated). We are using opaque tokens and ([as indicated by the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver-opaque-introspector-dsl)) have a security config of the following form:

```
@Configuration
public static class OAuthWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().mvcMatchers("/path/to/api/**").hasAuthority(CUSTOM_SCOPE)
            .oauth2ResourceServer().opaqueToken().introspector(opaqueTokenIntrospector());
    }
}
```

Here `opaqueTokenIntrospector()` is a bean which performs the following tasks:

- Send a request to the introspection endpoint to get the full token.
- Also send a request to the userinfo endpoint to get additional info about the user from the IDP.
- Map some of this additional info into custom spring roles and add these roles to the authenticated user.

The way this configuration is set up, each request to the API comes with two *additional* requests: one to the introspection endpoint and one to the userinfo endpoint. It would be better to save on some of these if a user performs successive requests to the API.

**Is it possible to save the result of the `opaqueTokenIntrospector()` in the session of the user? This way the whole flow of the bean need only be done once per user, saving on redundant requests.**

Answer (score 0):

This is a common requirement when you get beyond basic APIs. Use a claims caching solution, which is an API gateway pattern:

When a token is first received do the lookups and save them into an object:

- Token claims
- User info claims
- App specific claims

Then cache the results against the token, so that subsequent requests with the same token are fast:

- Use a thread safe cache - my preference is to use an in memory one
- Use the SHA256 hash of the access token as the key
- Use the serialized claims as the value

This probably goes beyond Spring's default behaviour, but you can customise it.

I have a Java sample that does this - here are a couple of links, though my sample is quite a complex one:

- [Custom Authorizer Class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthorizer.java)
- [Caching Class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/claims/ClaimsCache.java)
- [Java Write Up](https://authguidance.com/2019/03/24/java-spring-boot-api-oauth-coding/)